# Centering a table on the page

Tags: pgfplotstable

## Centering a table on the page

I have some tables that I am generating with external text files. There are lots of different tables, but they all share some of the same requirements.

- They need to extend to the margins of the page.
- The table needs several header rows. This example shows one header row that takes all 14 columns. The row needs to be white text on a colored background.
- The rows need to alternate colors.
- There are one or more rows that need to stretch/widen as required.

I am nearly there, but with a few issues:

- The table doesn't respect the margins of the
- The header row does not extend the full length of the table. When rendered, it is a bit short on both sides of the row.
- Why does the first row start with a 0?
- When emacs goes to reindent the file, I get the thing you see below. It makes me think I am missing some syntax.

Here is the source code for the above, and a screenshot of what I am seeing on render.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, string type, column type=,
  begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccccccccccccc}},
                 end table={\end{tabularx}},
               every head row/.style={ 
                 before row={
                   \multicolumn{14}{l}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\textcolor{white}{Here is a very long and wordy title}}}}\\
                 }
               },
               every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
               font=\footnotesize
               ]{data.csv}
             \end{table}

           \end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated to the issue, but you can clean up your preamble a bit. There is for instance no need to load `xcolor` twice. You also don't need to load `colortbl` since it is already loaded by `xcolor` when used with the `table` option.

Comment: Thanks! I made those updates, and everything still renders.

Comment: To make the table fit into the textwidth, you can add the `calc` package to your preamble and use the following: `before row={
                   \rowcolor{black}\multicolumn{14}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\textcolor{white}{Here is a very long and wordy title}}\\ `

Comment: Okay, this works for now. I now need to figure out exactly what's going on. Let me do that, and I'll build an in depth answer to this..

Answer (score 3):

Use a suitable dimension for the title box (you need to remove the outer padding from the text width). Also use all `X` columns.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for a very long title

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  string type,
  column type=,
  begin table={
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{14}{X}}
  },
  end table={\end{tabularx}},
  every head row/.style={ 
    before row={%
      \multicolumn{14}{@{}c@{}}{%
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
            \textcolor{white}{Here is a very long and wordy title}%
          }%
        }%
      }\\
    },
  },
  every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
  font=\footnotesize
]{\jobname.csv}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  string type,
  column type=,
  begin table={
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{14}{X}}
  },
  end table={\end{tabularx}},
  every head row/.style={ 
    before row={%
      \multicolumn{14}{@{}c@{}}{%
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
            \textcolor{white}{\lipsum[2]}%
          }%
        }%
      }\\
    },
  },
  every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
  font=\footnotesize
]{\jobname.csv}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My heartiest felicitations on passing the 800k points reputation mark on TeX.SE!!!

Comment: @egreg how is the outer padding removed

Answer (score 1):

In this case the title will fit easily, so no `\parbox` is needed.  However, if the title is too long, you can measure the width without the title and use that.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \sbox0{% measure width without title
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, string type,
               every head row/.style={output empty row},
               every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
               font=\footnotesize
               ]{data.csv}%
  }% end of savebox
  \centering
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, string type,
               every head row/.style={output empty row,
                 before row={
                   \multicolumn{14}{c}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\wd0-2\tabcolsep}{\textcolor{white}{\blindtext}}}}\\
                 }
               },
               every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
               font=\footnotesize
               ]{data.csv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]