# Multiple headers with multiple columns

Tags: tabularx, pgfplotstable

## Multiple headers with multiple columns

I am currently working on creating a table with multiple headers spanning multiple columns. I asked about first head [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526463/centering-a-table-on-the-page), and got the first one taken care of, but I am not sure how to break up the other headers.

I would like a general solution/explanation on how to present these headers in varying layouts.

I have attached a sample in html, and the source I am using to render is here:

[image: HTML representation of file]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.csv}
a, b, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
a, b, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
a, b, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for a very long title

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htp]
  \centering

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  string type,
  column type=,
  begin table={
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{14}{X}}
      },
      end table={\end{tabularx}},
    every head row/.style={ 
      before row={%
        \multicolumn{14}{@{}c@{}}{%
          \colorbox{black}{%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
              \textcolor{white}{This header belongs to the entire table}%
            }%
          }%
        }\\
        \multicolumn{14}{@{}c@{}}{%
          \colorbox{gray}{%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
              \textcolor{white}{This belongs to the letters. header1 header2 header3}%
            }%
          }%
        }\\
      },
    },
    every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
    font=\footnotesize
    ]{datafile.csv}

  \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely crucial to surround each cell with a separate "frame"? Please advise.

Comment: I don't want borders around the cells. I rendered the demo table with frames just so it was easier to see how the headers worked; by emphasizing the "colspans".

Comment: The attached tex script renders what I need, other than the headers spanning multiple columns.